# How do I keep lines starting with a list of numbers (linux)?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file that looks like this:

```
0   123   word
1   324   word
2   234   word
3   53    word
4   666   word
5   23    word
6   4     word
...
```

I have been trying to keep only the lines starting with some numbers. I have the numbers in a file that looks like this:

```
2
4
5
...
```

So the final file should look like this:

```
2   234   word
4   666   word
5   23    word
...
```

I think I can get lines starting with a specific character using grep (grep "2" input > output), but doing it one by one is not viable and I do not know how to do it for a list of numbers in a file. Could someone help me with that?

Comment: You can use `[a,b,c,d]` to match one of the elements between the brackets. So based on you example, `grep ^[2,4,5] file` is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a {print}' file1 file2
```

where `file1` contains the numbers to keep, one per line, and `file2` is the file to filter.